# How to make information appear only when hovered over using jquery and css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a navigation that only drops down to display the information desired, along with a slight fade in effect, but only when I hover over the selection. I am not too familiar with jquery, but my professor showed me this code to get my desired effect. I am unsure of how to make the effect work only when I hover over it.

here is my code for html:

```
<div id="wrap"> 

 <div id="tabwrap"> 
  <ul id="tabs">
  <li class="current">
  <a href="#bacon" class="cyan">Terms</a>
  </li>

  <li>
  <a href="#batfish" class="green">Resources</a>
  </li> 

  <li>
  <a href="#tuna" class="lav">Culture</a>
  </li> 

   <li>
   <a href="#sausage" class="teal">Share</a>
    </li>

    </ul> 

   <div id="content"> 
   <div id="bacon" class="current animated"> <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet
    ribeye short loin leberkas andouille jerky meatloaf pork spare ribs
    corned beef. Andouille ham hock ground round, shankle pastrami rump
    hamburger filet mignon. </p></div>
    <div id="batfish" class="animated"><p>Batfish warmouth orbicular
    combtooth blenny; madtom, knifefish handfish rock beauty armorhead
    frogfish. Cownose ray pupfish pencilfish char fangtooth marblefish
    longfin dragonfish armored searobin hamlet.</p></div>

<div id="tuna" class="animated"><p>Tuna, sculpin squeaker rice eel, lamprey
 triggerfish mooneye African glass catfish, loach wolf-eel yellowhead
 jawfish grass carp sea dragon neon tetra. Fingerfish forehead brooder
 sarcastic fringehead sixgill ray, scaly dragonfish bluntnose minnow.</p
 </div>

 <div id="sausage" class="animated"> <p>Sausage ground round sirloin ham
  hock t-bone tongue strip steak meatloaf landjaeger shankle andouille.
  Turducken doner brisket, shank salami shoulder kevin filet mignon ball tip
  chicken.</p> 
   </div> <!-- End of Div-->

  </div> <!-- End of Div-->
```

my css is:

```
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing:   
border-box;  margin: 0; padding: 0; }

 #wrap { width: 75%; margin: 0 auto; min-width: 300px; max-width: 1400px; }

 #tabwrap {
background: #fff;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
min-height: 300px;
margin: 10px auto;
/*box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ddd;*/
/*border: 1px solid #ddd;*/
}
 #tabs { overflow: hidden; background: #777; }
 #tabs li { list-style: none; }
 #tabs li a {
float: left;
display: block;
padding: 10px;
color: #fff;
width: 25%;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
border-right: 1px solid #555;
border-left: 1px solid #888;
font-size: 15px;

}

#tabs li a:hover { background: #666; }
#tabs li:first-child a { border-left: 0; }
#tabs li:last-child a { border-right: 0; }

 #tabs li.current a {
background: #fff;
color: #666;

}

#tabs li.current a.cyan{
background: cyan;
color: #666;
}

#tabs li.current a.green{
background-color: rgb(100,200,100);
color: #666;
}

#tabs li.current a.lav{
background-color: rgb(200,200,255);
color: #666;
}


#tabs li.current a.teal{
background-color: rgb(95,200,165);
color: #666;
}



#content > div {
clear: both;
padding: 20px;
line-height: 19px;
color: #666;
/*text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;*/
display: none;
}
.animated {
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
   -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
     -o-animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-duration: 2s;
 }

 #content .current { display: block }
 #content p { margin: 0 0 20px 0;}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeft {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);
   transform: translateX(-10px);
 }

 100% {
 opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: translateX(0);
transform: translateX(0);
}
 }

@keyframes fadeInLeft {
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);
-ms-transform: translateX(-10px);
transform: translateX(-10px);
}

100% {
 opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: translateX(0);
-ms-transform: translateX(0);
transform: translateX(0);
  }
 }

.fadeInLeft {
-webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
 animation-name: fadeInLeft;
 }

  #bacon {
  background-color: cyan;
 }

  #batfish {
  background-color: rgb(100,200,100);
  }

  #tuna {
  background-color: rgb(200,200,255);
  }

  #sausage {
  background-color: rgb(95,200,165);
   }
```

my js is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#tabs li a').hover(function(e) {
  $('#tabs li, #content
.current').removeClass('current').removeClass
('fadeInLeft'); 
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $(currentTab).addClass('current fadeInLeft');
    e.preventDefault();

});
});
```

Comment: You could just ask your professor; I'm sure he'd be glad someone's paying attention and willing to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hover function seems to work just fine for the enter function, but you are missing the leave function.

```
$('element').hover(function(){
  //enter code here
}, function(){
  //leave code here
});
```

Try something like this:

```
$('#tabs li a').hover(function(e) {
    $('#tabs li, #content .current').removeClass('current').removeClass('fadeInLeft'); 
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $(currentTab).addClass('current fadeInLeft');
    e.preventDefault();

}, function(){
   $('#tabs li, #content .current').removeClass('current').removeClass('fadeInLeft');
});
```

Comment: When provided with a single argument, `.hover()` uses it for both enter and exit.

Comment: This does give me the desired effect I want, however, when you first load the page, the information for the first tab is already down, until I hover over and then the effect takes place. How do I change that, so when you load the page, it's just the nav and then the pull down hover effect.

Comment: @Lubidia13, remove the current class from the `<li>` and remove both the current and animated classes from the `<div>`. That will get you a clear start.

Comment: @Ouroborus, what you say is true, it just wouldn't help in this scenario since he is adding the classes back in the same function. The leaving function needs to remove the classes only.

Comment: Thank you so much for the assistance! I really appreciate it.